# Recently my desktop has a lot of "extra" icons on it which seem to be duplicates

Tags: desktop-icons

Recently my desktop looks like this.

[image]

Looking at it, there are "duplicates" of the icons.
But I can't move any of them and none will open if I double click on them.

The "bin" (bottom right) won't open either.

Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: Try alt+f2 then type r and enter

Comment: try to reboot, it restart most services and maybe can help you.

Comment: silly question, but can you try changing your background image?

Comment: What file manager are you running?

Comment: Compare it with the contents of the `~/Desktop/` directory. Also, you could try in the `gnome-tweaks` app's Extensions tab, to disable/re-enable the "Desktop icons" extension...

Comment: Ok, Tried <alt>+<F2> and <r>.   For a second it was good, then the "extra" icons came back.
Rebbot....   This happens every time I boot.
Background image changed.  No difference.
Filemanager:   Um...   Dunno.   How do I find this out?   Ubuntu 20.10
Oh, I do have two installed.   "Files" and "PCManFM"  But I'm not sure that is what you mean.
Compare to "~/Desktop"  I think there are twice as many icons on the desktop as shown in the direcotry.
Gnome-tweaks....    Apps extension tab.   Nah.  Not there.   Extensions.   Turned off desktop icons.  No change.

Comment: On file manager:  me@me-desktop:~/Downloads$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop

Comment: For the sake of trying, I made a directory in the "desktop" drawer and put all other files/folders in it.   Restarted and got a desktop with a "home" icon and 2 x icons for the new directory I made.    So the problem looks systemic to me.